# Did this stormtrooper in “The Force Awakens” have a name?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, character-identification

In *The Force Awakens* when the protagonists reach Maz Kanata’s castle and are abruptly attacked by the Kylo Ren and the First Order, an unnamed Stormtrooper has a scuffle with Finn, showing off his bad-ass riot control baton and taking down Finn in the process, who was armed with the lightsaber. He is unfortunately killed by Han moments later.

[image: Riot Control Stormtrooper]

For some reason this has turned into a meme, with many dubbing him TR-8R, or Tray Tor because of what he says to Finn. Does he actually have a real name?

Comment: "Unfortunately"?

Comment: Can't wait for the retcon that makes his name officially TR-8R!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Update: The Starwars.com website have [officially named this character](http://www.starwars.com/news/meet-fn-2199-a-k-a-tr-8r-the-stormtrooper-behind-the-meme) as **FN-2199**, one of the stormtrooper trainees who served with Finn in the star wars prequel novel [Before the Awakening](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Before_the_Awakening)

> **MEET FN-2199, A.K.A. TR-8R:**
>
> ***His name is FN-2199. But his friends call him “Nines.”*** As detailed in
>   Greg Rucka’s excellent book Before the Awakening, Nines trained and
>   served on a squad with Finn (then FN-2187) in the First Order. That
>   explains why he seems just a little extra angry upon seeing Finn
>   during the attack on Maz’s Castle. You can see FN-2199 in the image
>   below by Phil Noto from Before the Awakening — he’s the trooper seated
>   in the background with red hair. Who’d have thought?

[image]

Hat tip to [@AlfredoHernández](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112466/did-this-stormtrooper-in-the-force-awakens-have-a-name/112470#comment274897_112470)

---

<s>There's not been a character name released for him yet. The official [Star Wars Databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/first-order-riot-control-stormtroopers) refers to him as...</s>

> "**Riot Control Stormtrooper**"

and the screenplay just refers to him as "Stormtrooper"

> FINN SURPRISES A STORMTROOPER WITH THE LIGHTSABER, then another!
>   Untrained, he's athletic, brave, impressive. One Stormtrooper has a
>   MACE --
>
> **STORMTROOPER:** *Traitor!*
>
> FINN and the TROOPER WITH THE MACE battle. The Mace Trooper KNOCKS
>   FINN DOWN! The Stormtrooper is about to end him, when THE STORMTROOPER
>   IS SHOT AND FALLS!

---

He's not named in the film's [junior novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(junior_novelization))

> The troopers were as startled as Finn when he sliced through armor,
>   bone, and flesh. Two he cut down immediately. The third trooper
>   dropped his rifle and brandished a melee weapon of his own, a riot
>   control baton that crackled with blue electricity. Finn swung at him,
>   but the trooper ducked and shoved Finn backward, off his feet. The
>   trooper had raised his baton to finish Finn when a blaster bolt
>   finished the trooper instead.

Nor in the [Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel))

> A third came at him with a close-quarters weapon and the two locked in
>   combat. Despite lack of any training with a lightsaber, Finn was
>   athletic and courageous. In tandem with such traits, the saber made
>   him a formidable fighter.
>
> The trooper who had engaged Finn was big, strong, and agile. Finn
>   realized the fight would have long since been over if not for the
>   trooper’s regard for the lethal potential of the lightsaber. That
>   didn’t stop him from finally knocking Finn to the ground and raising
>   his own weapon for a killing strike—only to fall backward, shot before
>   he could deliver the blow.

Nor in any of the film's official merchandise

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 24):

Not in the current canon.

- He's not credited specially as far as I know by name

  *(the only 2 credited are  Michael Giacchino's FN-3181, and  Nigel Godrich's FN-9330; neither of them is described by anyone as being in that scene. One was supposedly the one arresting Poe, another one was supposedly  the one Han shot <strike>first</strike> on Starkiller base later)*
- He has no name in the [Foster's novelization](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112434/976)
- There's no specific trooper mentioned as excelling with melee weapon in the prequel novel "Before the Awakening".

There's a chance that (based on him yelling "Traitor") he's one of Finn's close chums in the prequel book. Since Slip (FN-2003) was *presumably* - at least based on how he was described in the prequels - the one who got himself killed off on Jakku (and even if not, the one Finn always helped before so I don't see him insulting Finn and trying to kill him), that leaves:

- FN-2199, aka Nines (UPDATE: Starwars.com [confirmed that this was Nines](http://www.starwars.com/news/meet-fn-2199-a-k-a-tr-8r-the-stormtrooper-behind-the-meme), hat/tip @AlfredoHernández)
- FN-2000, aka Zeros

Comment: Polygon wrote an article, [The canonical story behind TR-8R, the internet's new favorite stormtrooper](http://www.polygon.com/2015/12/30/10690288/the-canonical-story-behind-tr-8r-the-internets-new-favorite), that reaches the same conclusion. Apparently your hunch about Slip is confirmed, too

Comment: It's definitely Nines: http://www.starwars.com/news/meet-fn-2199-a-k-a-tr-8r-the-stormtrooper-behind-the-meme

Comment: @user568458 - I'll need to re-read it, but when I read it the first time, I was under impression that they had no evidence for Slip, just a guess

Comment: @AlfredoHernández - OK, I'm not sure if it's just me being dumb, but reading that article, what's their actual proof that TR-8R is Nines? Did I miss something due to undersleep? (quite possible :)

Comment: @AlfredoHernández - never mind, I'm being dumb. The article IS canon since it's on Starwars.com :)  Thanks!

Comment: @AlfredoHernández - I've edited a hat tip into my answer as well. You have my personal +1

Comment: @Richard, no problem. I would've written a new answer, but DVK's answer was already spot on in suspecting Nines and Zeros.

Comment: @AlfredoHernández - It's up to you. If you do write an answer, I'll sling a small bounty on it to make sure you get your just rewards.

Comment: @Richard, nah, no need. But thanks ;)

Comment: @AlfredoHernández - the need is there in a sense of, a good deed should be properly attributed and properly rewarded. Even if you personally don't feel the need for reward, socially it's an important thing, IMHO.

Comment: @DVK the article has an "update" at the end linking to a tweeted image from the visual dictionary that labels the helmet blood stain as "FN-2003's blood"

Comment: Oh, yeah, agreed. But in all honesty, I wouldn't have remembered to come here if it wasn't because I previously read this question/answer earlier today. Generally, when I answer a question, I want it to really make a difference from what's been previously; this really felt like a comment (although you could easily argue that it deserved its own answer, as it was the main question, but whatever :P)

Answer (score -1):

Nines has apparently been confirmed as the squadmate who dies and streaks blood on Finn's mask. Zeros is a strong melee focused trooper who seems to have always had a beef with Finn. Nothing is for sure, but the good betting money is that "TR-8R" is actually FN-2000. Plus, if you see the guy he looks pretty awesome with his helmet off, with a big face scar and everything, so personally I'd love it to be him.

Comment: Do you have a source?  Where was it confirmed that Nines died?

Comment: According to this question the trooper who put blood on Finn was FN-2003: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111958/does-fn-stand-for-or-mean-anything