# What were the first humans with alphanumeric designations?

Tags: history-of, names

In *The Force Awakens*, we meet this guy, FN-2187 (Finn)
,

[image: Finn looking shocked after arriving on Jakku]

and it's a plot point that the Stormtroopers in this era don't have given names besides [the corps and a number](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111971/3823).

However, aside from that, they are just normal humans.

What's the first instance of naming humans this way?

---

What is not included:

- aliens, cyborgs, robots, etc.
- instances where someone else refers to them by an alphanumeric designation, say to depersonalized them or because they are being observed or cataloged or because of their function, but they actually do have names (or did at one point)
- purely numeric or alphabetic designations

What is included:

- all SF universes, in-universe
- *first* means first created in the real world.

Comment: Obviously it's later than 1921's We, but THX-1138 is earlier than FN-2187.

Comment: Are you asking for in-universe instances or real-world instances?

Comment: So you're not much into common Roman names like Quintus, Sextus, Septimus, Octavus? Create in the real world refers to Sci-Fi, still?

Comment: Well, the first human with a numeric designation was probably "1"

Comment: Doesn’t your second criterion exclude Finn as well? Unless I’m misremembering, he was taken from his family as an infant, so presumably he did have a name once, even if he doesn’t remember it.

Comment: It's been a long time since I looked at it, but I recall that Qabalistic (Ancient Hebrew) names had numerical designations that produced alphabetic names.

Comment: @JohnP, I believe what you're referring to is merely that number numbers were/are written using values assigned to each letter, which means that one can compute a value to any word and thus assign all kinds of mystical interpretation to it.    But that is not the same as having an alphanumeric name because all letters were/are effectively numbers as well.

Comment: @ThePopMachine could be, its been 30 yts since I had the class.

Answer (score 40):

*We*, by  Yevgeny Zamyatin, completed in 1921 in Russian, first published in 1924 in English, concerns a world state in which everyone is known by an alphanumeric code, and people are referred to as "numbers."  The protagonist is (in English) D-503.  Other major characters include R-13, O-90, and I-330.  In general, males have consonants and odd numbers; women have vowels and even numbers.

Comment: Well, that handily beats THX-1138...

Comment: And, even beats Ayn Rand's Anthem by about a decade. For those wondering, Ayn Rand wrote Anthem in 1937. In this future, dystopian setting, everyone is referred to by alphanumeric designations such as 'Equality 7-2521'. (Does this even count because of the whole word 'Equality' here?)

Answer (score 32):

I present you with a 19th century example, in a play from 1861.

[The Tragedy of Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tragedy_of_Man) has several scenes which can be considered science-fiction: set in the future, it describes a different human society which uses futuristic technology, and the relation between technology and society are an important aspect in the story.

The story goes through many eras of human history, from biblical times, through classical antiquity, middle ages and the author's present, but the last scenes are set in the future. Scene 12 presents a highly technocratic society, where poetry and emotions are banned, every member has one and only one job, and people are referred to only by numbers. They don't seem to have had any names.

Note: the protagonist recognizes them as expys of various historical figures he met during his time travels / dreams in earlier scenes, or, they remind him of those historical figures. I would still argue that this doesn't invalidate *"being observed or cataloged or because of their function, but they actual do have names"*, for me it seems to have been included to exclude prisoners etc. who have real names used by other people.

Comment: If "people are referred to only by numbers", then how is this *alpha*numeric?

Comment: @Psychonaut: *numeric* is a subset of *alphanumeric.* It’s just like every square is a rectangle or every linear equation system is a non-linear equation system.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: This can't possibly be what the OP was asking about, since alphabetic names are also a subset of alphanumeric, and alphabetic names have been used since time immemorial.

Comment: @Psychonaut: *alphabetic names have been used since time immemorial* – Nope. The names you are referring to exist in spoken language first and representing them with letters using an orthography for that language is secondary (and much newer). This is quite a different thing from using letters without any intention to phonetically capture of a spoken word.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Regardless, the point is any book with a name in it would count, so the first would probably be some random ancient scroll.

Comment: @Psychonaut However, I'd argue that the question asks for alphanumeric *designations*, so I'd assume names are excluded. Eg. "John" wouldn't count (unless it was by chance in an alpha-designation system), but "jNoOCxdRhnNUp" would.

Comment: @Feathercrown: That’s exactly the point I was making. *John* uses letters to reflect some pronunciation. *jNoOCxdRhnNUp* uses letters for their own sake.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Ah, I misread your comment. We are in agreement, then.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft there are exceptions, though, like your name, which is (apparently) not derivated of any known spoken language, but doesn't seem to belong to a normal alphanumerical system.

Is that keyboard-headbanging? :)

Comment: *like your name, which is (apparently) not derivated of any known spoken language* – That is not correct. It is a phonetic approximation of mumbled Bavarian. See my profile for details.

Comment: Sorry, but I'd wanted to include numerical designations,  I would have mentioned it.   That's a qualitatively different question.   Even if an argument can be made that *alphanumeric* is a superset off *numeric*, that interpretation is context-dependent,  and not the intent of the question.

Answer (score 2):

(I don't know if the alphanumeric badges in this story are personal designations or not, but I'm posting this as an answer anyway. If it gets too many downvotes I'll delete it.)

**1916** A few years earlier than *We*, but you can argue about whether it's a real example: [*Enoch Soames*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?97004), a novelette by [Max Beerbohm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Beerbohm), first published in the May 1916 issue of [*The Century Magazine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Century_Magazine); available at [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/760), the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/centurymagazine92newyrich), and [The Hathi Institute](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.32106017174555;view=1up;seq=7). From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enoch_Soames) summary:

> On the afternoon of 3 June 1897, Soames and Beerbohm are having lunch in the [Soho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soho)-based "Restaurant du Vingtieme Siecle". Soames is self-obsessed and deeply depressed; consumed with the belief that he is an unrecognised great author of literature and poetry, unhappy about his current obscurity and failure, and keenly curious about his "certain" fate of posthumous fame. Despairing and desperate for assurance of the eventual recognition of his works and talent, Soames agrees to a contract offered by the [Devil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil), who introduces himself from a neighbouring table. In exchange for the future possession of his soul, Soames will be transported exactly 100 years forward in time; to spend one afternoon (from 2:10 PM to 7 PM) in the [Reading Room](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Museum_Reading_Room) of the [British Museum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Museum), a world-renowned center for bibliographic research, to discover what judgement posterity will make on himself and his works. After the allotted time has expired, Soames will be returned to their present date and location, but at the same time of evening as his departure from the future; and the Devil will then collect his payment.

On Soames' return from the future, he is questioned by the author and first-person narrator, Max Beerbohm:

> "That's right. Try to remember everything. Eat a little more bread. What did the reading-room look like?"
>
> "Much as usual," he at length muttered.
>
> "Many people there?"
>
> "Usual sort of number."
>
> "What did they look like?"
>
> Soames tried to visualise them. "They all," he presently remembered, "looked very like one another."
>
> My mind took a fearsome leap. "All dressed in Jaeger?"
>
> "Yes. I think so. Greyish-yellowish stuff."
>
> **"A sort of uniform?" He nodded. "With a number on it, perhaps?—a number on a large disk of metal sewn on to the left sleeve? DKF 78,910—that sort of thing? It was even so.**  "And all of them—men and women alike—looking very well-cared-for? very Utopian? and smelling rather strongly of carbolic? and all of them quite hairless?" I was right every time. Soames was only not sure whether the men and women were hairless or shorn. "I hadn't time to look at them very closely," he explained.

For the purposes of this answer, I'm assuming that the alphanumeric DKF 78,910 is a personal designation. There is no explanation in the story; those alphanumeric things are not mentioned again. Apparently regular names also exist in that fictional 1997, to wit, the author T. K. Nupton:

> I went back to the middle desk and asked what was the best modern book on late nineteenth-century literature. They told me Mr. T. K. Nupton's book was considered the best. I looked it up in the catalogue and filled in a form for it. It was brought to me.

That's not necessarily a problem; no reason important people like Mr. Nupton can't have traditional names, while the masses get by with letters and numbers.

Comment: This is a good find, but kind of inconclusive as you point out yourself.